# how to include this laravel code @json(auth()->user()) in my webpack

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have this code added in my `master.blade.php` so that I can use the user data in my vue.js application

```
@auth
     <script>
          window.authUser = @json(auth()->user())
     </script>
@endauth
```

But unfortunately this code will display all user information when you go to "view page source". Is there a way where I can include this peace of code in my webpack? Or is there any other way I can hide the users data while assigning it to `window.authUser`?

Comment: No, webpack cannot do this for you. You should specify only the fields you absolutely need to show, and not give up your entire model.

Comment: Any data accessible to JavaScript is also accessible to the user. Output just the specific items from the User model you require, and remember that a malicious user will be able to see it all.

Comment: The first question you should ask yourself though is "would this cause any problems?". What sensitive data are you storing in your user instance that should never be visible?

Comment: If you want to hide sensitive fields, just use `$hidden` in the model

Comment: Thank you for all your comments and sharing your wisdom on this matter. Maybe I have to find another approach other than using this built in `@json(auth()->user())` in laravel or apply above suggestions.

Answer (score -2):

<s>You shouldn't bind user data into `window` because it will be available to everyone with a little technical knowledge, instead try utilizing `local storage` or less lived `session storage`</s>

You can always encrypt user data and save it inside one of the storages mentioned above, it is true that it is accessible too. The data you are trying to store inside `Vue` will be available to the potential attacker always, because it is on the client side. Another suggestion which you can think about is using `vuex` to store your data

Comment: Data in localStorage or JavaScript's session storage is similarly available to a malicious user - you can view it right in the browser's web developer console, or access it via the JS console.

Comment: An additional note on the update: If Vue can decrypt the data, so can a malicious user. There's fundamentally no safe way to make data available to Vue without the user also being able to access it.

Comment: There is no real way of `hiding` data which lives on the client-side. That data will always be visible, yes, but I think in his case, he has to store that data on the client side, so it's no more a question of is it safe, because it is not, but whats the best place to save it and what

Comment: thats not the OP's question. The OP's question is hiding the data, not keeping it safe or the "best" way to store data on the client side. Regardless, I think all methods are equally "safe"

Comment: Thank you guys for sharing your wisdom on this matter. By reading on your comments maybe I'll find other best way approach on this matter and if I can't then maybe apply the suggestions above.